# heroku platform access lost (login email no longer accessible)

Tags: authentication, heroku

My company has lost access to Heroku platform. Some day, for some reason the password stopped working (the password was correct as this was pulled from our password management registry). Since the email account used as a login attribute does no longer exist, we can't recover the access.

I also can't reach the Heroku support as they block any support emails from free accounts.

So I have to ask the question on the community forum. This is the user experience nightmare.

We can't get the login email access back, as all the data got completely deleted when we changed our company's branding (thus the domain)

Is there any possibility to contact their support so I can prove our company identity and the account ownership?

Answer (score 1):

> My company has lost access to Heroku platform. Some day, for some reason the password stopped working (the password was correct as this was pulled from our password management registry).

It is likely that the password was changed as part of [the ongoing security mitigation that Heroku is performing](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413). I received notice that this was going to happen via email, as I suspect all customers did. Password resets began on May 4 and, per the previous link, are now complete.

> Since the email account used as a login attribute does no longer exist, we can't recover the access.

This is a good reminder of the importance of keeping such accounts current. Not only would you have received notification that the password reset was coming, you would also be able to recover your account now.

Ideally, this would have been an email address on a domain you control so you could recreate the account or add it as an alias for an existing user, then perform a password reset. But it sounds like that isn't the case. If you still have the old domain registered, this is still probably the easiest solution.

If you absolutely cannot create a new account with the old domain I suggest you create a new paid account and submit a ticket asking to have the old account recovered. Whether Heroku will accept your request is up to them. I'm not sure what kind of proof they'll require.

For a variety of reasons, [we cannot help much beyond this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Either get control of the old email address or get in touch with Heroku support somehow.

Once you're through this, I suggest you audit the credentials used across all services and make sure they are current. Using a shared account or email alias like `dev@example.org` for these kinds of things can make this simpler moving forward.